# Is XMR private to Wallet Providers?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ringct, mymonero, stealth-address

If XMR Wallet Providers kept logs, would they be able to identify the amount of transactions and the addresses involved in transactions? Do compromised Wallet Providers pose a risk to XMR privacy and make ringct and stealth addresses ineffective? What are the safest ways to send and receive Monero?

Answer (score 0):

> If XMR Wallet Providers kept logs, would they be able to identify the amount of transactions and the addresses involved in transactions?

They would certainly have that *ability*, if they wanted to, and depending on how they implement.

> Do compromised Wallet Providers pose a risk to XMR privacy and make ringct and stealth addresses ineffective?

Generally speaking, the only people that can be affected are the users of such providers.

> What are the safest ways to send and receive Monero?

Use an official/open-source wallet. Don't give out your personal information to people / services you trade with. Don't give out the same receiving address to different entities. At the network layer, use tor/i2p.